# decorating a class - decorate once forget about it?

Tags: python, decorator, interpreter

I succeeded in creating a decorator that decorates any types of classes, adding a standard interface to them all, for easy access, integration, etc...

I have resisted using metaclasses, as literature on this point says that it is an overkill and most times can be replaced by say class decorators. What troubles me is the following:

```
def Decorator(somearg):

    def wrapper(cls):
        clsinit = cls.__init__
        cls.members = []

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            #do something with somearg...
            self.__class__.members.append(self)
            clsinit(self,*args,**kwargs)

        cls.__init__ = clsinit
        return cls

    return wrapper

@Decorator('thearg')
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
b = A()
```

Using python debugger, at import time, class A is immediately decorated with argument 'thearg'. But each time I instantiate A(), the instance calls straight to the init defined in the decorator, without passing through the previous layers. That's great because I want my class to record each members and not be reset every time a new instance is instantiated. But I am not sure I understand why.

Can someone explain the physics of the python interpreter in this specific case?

Comment: There is something wrong with the code you posted. It has a SyntaxError, and may have the roles of `somearg` and `cls` flip flopped. Is it a simplified version of your real code? Please test and fix.

Comment: This is indeed the sort of thing that a metaclass should be used for. Decorators just can't handle it without explicitly decorating every subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, referring to the corrected code in your updated question, you ask:

> "But each time I instantiate A(), the instance calls straight to the
>   init defined in the decorator, without passing through the previous
>   layers."

It does this because when the`wrapper()`class decorator function, created by the`Decorator()` function, is applied to`class A`, it replaces`A`'s`__init__()`with its own dynamically defined `wrapper.__init__()`function. *That* function is what is called whenever `A`s are instantiated and it's written first do some things and then call the original`A.__init__()`at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just changing the class and not creating a new one, there's no need for a wrapper function (that should have been a wrapper class):

```
def Decorator(cls):
    clsinit = cls.__init__
    cls.members = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        clsinit(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.members.append(self)

    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls
```

BTW, you should just create a base class and inherit from it:

```
class Base(object):
    members = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.members.append(self)

class A(Base):
    pass
```

Much cleaner

Comment: I did make a mistake on my code: I edit it now. I made the wrapper function because I needed to use an argument at decoration time to somehow curry the instantiation. Also, I tried inheritance! But my problem is that the mother class becomes a container for all the subclasses which is unwanted behaviour. If I decorate, all the decorated classes become their own containers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JBernardo and @martineau for your answers. My objective with this code was to implement container like behaviour of the class objects in order to reach their instances more easily. But I want to access instances relative to each class one at a time, not all in the same inherited class.

Actually working on the code again helped me understand my issue:

a)Decorator is called with its argument somearg

b) the content of the next line (definition of class A) is used as the argument to the wrapper function. Inside this function I:
   1) remember the initial class init to avoid infinite recursion
   2) define a new init to make changes at instance level
   3) bind a new init method for the class
   4) return a transformed class object

c) because the return is a class object, every time I instantiate an instance, I go straight to init because this is how it was bound in the new class.